# For loop not working in nested block using Jinja 2

Tags: python-2.7, flask, jinja2

I have a flask app in which my parent block (using jinja 2) has a for-loop and I would like to make use of the parent for-loop in my meta block which is inside the parent block. The meta block is not recognizing the i variable and throws an error which says "    **UndefinedError: 'i' is undefined**". How do I make use of that variable in my meta block.

```
{% block content %}
    {% for i in airlines %}
        {% block meta %}
            <meta property="og:image" content="{{ i.ImageURL }}" />
        {% endblock meta %} 
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Secondly when I code in the below manner then I am getting the result using scoped but when I am trying to access the element for example "{{i.ImageURL}}" then it's not working.

```
{% block metaimage scoped %}
{{ i }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Does it work when you remove the  {% block meta %} +  {% endblock meta %} . Normally these are used as placeholder, and I cannot why you are using them here? I tested your code by passing a dictionary and only worked as soon as I removed the meta block placeholder. Question: what kind of object is airlines exactly?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
{% for i in airlines %}
    {% block content scoped %}
        {% block meta %}
            <meta property="og:image" content="{{ i.ImageURL }}" />
        {% endblock meta %} 
    {% endblock content %}
{% endfor %}
```